# When requesting GetMultipleItems is it possible to retrieve discount information?

Tags: ebay-api, ebay-sdk

I am trying to access the special discounts that sellers offer when you buy multiple products from their shop.
I am using `GetMultipleItems` to get the data on a large set of books and their prices however a lot of the products we buy are a lot cheaper when multiple products are purchased form one seller. I would like to reflect that price in my software so getting these offers from the API would be incredibly useful.

Like in this example
[image: Discounted price]
[Example offer](https://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/363713919088)

If anyone knows of a way to get that data it would be much appreciated.

**Edit**
After much searching I've found [this](https://developer.ebay.com/api-docs/sell/static/marketing/pm-volume-discounts.html) which is the information I need to get for each listing. But still no ways to get the info in a request.